# FileNotFound exception when deploying application to Azure

Tags: azure, docker

So, I have a spring boot application, and it in part takes in a file and reads the contents. It runs perfectly locally, but when I put it on a Docker image and deploy to azure, I get a file not found error. Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM [place]
VOLUME /tmp
ARG jarFileName
RUN mkdir /app 
COPY $jarFileName /app/app.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /app/app.jar'
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
COPY startup.sh /app/startup.sh
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/app/startup.sh"]
CMD ["startup.sh"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Dockerfile you posted, I think there are several places need to pay attention to.

The first is that the line `COPY $jarFileName /app/app.jar` will get the error if you do not pass the variable jarFileName in the command `docker run`.

The second is that you should check the current directory for the line `COPY startup.sh /app/startup.sh` if there is the file startup.sh.

The last is that the line `CMD ["startup.sh"]`, I think you should change it into `CMD ["./startup.sh"]`. Usually, we execute a shell script using the command `sh script.sh` or `./script.sh` if the script has the permission 'x'.